# Are there dictionaries which classify words by UK and USA usage?

Tags: dictionaries

Are there **dictionaries** which classify words by UK and USA usage?

This question supposes that there are words which are mainly used in the UK while others are used in the USA. Based on that, there are editions for Americans and editions for British.

Here are a few examples for differences:

[image]

Comment: Oxford, Macmillan, and most useful dictionaries note the variants and variations in usage among NAmE, BrE, etc. However, I don't think there are many separate editions published for specific usage demographics. Fortunately, in the main the various "dialects" are still mutually understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately dictionaries do not classify words *specifically* in this way.  If you look up a word, a dictionary may show its usage, for AmE or BrE for example, but there is no cross-reference except for certain *novelty books* which specifically cross-references British and US words.

Answer (score 1):

The online version of the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org) divides its English definitions into "British" and "American", under different tabs.

I think it chooses a user's default dictionary based on IP address or other locating mojo (I am not a computer person), so if you're in the US you see the American definitions by default but can switch tabs to see one of the other dictionaries' definitions.

So for example if you look up [*vest*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vest) in the UK, the top definition will be

> **noun** [ C ]
>   **C1** UK (US undershirt) **a type of underwear, often with no sleeves, that covers the upper part of the body, worn for extra warmth**:
>   *a cotton/wool/string vest.*
>   *She always wore a long-sleeved thermal vest in the winter.*

But under the US tab for *vest*, the first definition is

> **vest** *noun* <sup>[ C ]</sup> **(CLOTHING)**
>
> - a piece of clothing like a coat without sleeves that reaches to the waist:
>     *My grandfather always wore his vest buttoned up.*
>     *The state requires that there be a life vest for each person in the boat.*

As you can see, even the formatting is different between the two tabs, so I suspect they're actually based on different dictionaries.

Sometimes tabs for other specialty dictionaries also appear; for example *vest* has a "Business" dictionary entry.